# Reference Image is pink

Tags: modeling, objects, image

I am trying to model an object, however when I import a jpg file it shows up as pink.
[image]

Comment: How are you trying to import it? - Drag and drop or Add > Image > Reference menu?

Comment: @JohnEason Ive tried importing it via Add > Image > Reference and also tried to drag it straight from the folder into blender.

Comment: Does the file open ok in an external image editor? If so it should load into Blender without problem.

Comment: @JohnEason is there a different way you do it? if so let me know please. I opened it in another image editor and it showed up fine.

Comment: Nope. Those are the only two ways I know of importing reference images. I always use the Add > Image > Reference route myself and have never had a problem.

Comment: @JohnEason I exported it as a png. it fixed the problem, thank you for the tip with the image editor!

Comment: Glad to hear you've sorted it. Must have been an odd format JPG file that Blender couldn't display.